# Stop Scala colossus http server

Tags: scala, colossus

I´m working with Scala Colossus and everything it´s fine so far, but I cannot find a way to stop the server. And looking in the documentation it´s not mention at all.

Any idea suggestion  please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a `Shutdown` command to the actor basically. Have a look at the source [here](https://github.com/tumblr/colossus/blob/1564e677680de88b554fd94b49b61eb72d9a3314/colossus/src/main/scala/colossus/core/Server.scala#L499).

Looks like what you want is, assuming you have a `serverRef: ServerRef` that you obtained via `val serverRef = Server.apply(config)`:

```
serverRef ! Shutdown
```

Naturally you can use `ask` and block or whatever flow control you want to achieve, but the way to interact with the server is via commands.

Comment: Thanks, the framework looks pretty neat, but I think need a lot of work in documentation

Comment: By the way, any idea why after I shutdown the server the ip it´s not released?. I´m running/stopping the server per Unit test, and the second test it´s getting bindAddress exception because the ip it´s in used. I´m using to stop the server shutdown as you suggest and even die() and nothing. Any suggestion?

Comment: @paul You're stopping the server asynchronously, you have no guarantee it's fully stopped before the next test kicks in. It's a bad idea to have one server per test, it's a pretty slow way to do it. Just use `BeforeAndAfterAll` if you are using ScalaTest. You will need to use `ask` and `Await.result` if you need to make sure the server has fully stopped before some other action.

Comment: Sorry I never use "akka" this is my first time. Can you provide me an example on how to use "ask" in this case?. Thanks you so much!